# Is this a proper way to use get in php

Tags: php, function, get

I'm using the below for get in php without a form.

```
If($q)
{
header("location:d.php?q=$name");
}
```

Is it correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html), the URI in the location header must be an absolute URI.

But regardless of this, your code will create an (unnecessary?) redirect.

If you want to persist values between requests, a better way would to use [**sessions**](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php).

Comment: Great idea....another question....can I have a session started on one page...and destroy when the user goes to the third page? Also will it conflict the already used session for login?

Comment: @Chrism: You can only have one session afaik. Why not use the "login session" and why do you want to destroy the session at all? You can just delete the values if this is what you want.

Comment: +1 for sessions. It's surprising how many php devs don't know about them

Comment: It is for storing the name when a user submits a form which should be valid only unto three pages. If I don't destroy and user goes for another sign up, there will be a conflict...ny idea?

Comment: @Chrism: As I said. Delete the name if you don't need it anymore.

Comment: Can u give me a link on how to delete the name in a session..sorry jspust getting started..thnks

Comment: I know how to start it and destroy it using session_destroy()

Comment: Or if not a link, just an idea...you have been very helpful.

Comment: Well, all the data in a session is available via the `$_SESSION` variable. It is an array. So assuming the name is contained in `$_SESSION['name']`, you can use `unset` to remove the value from the array: `unset($_SESSION['name'])` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php). Or you assign `null` to it.

Answer (score 1):

Although relative ones usually work, the URL specified by `location:` must be an absolute URL.

Other than that, we don't know what you are doing of course, but it's an okay header redirect to another address. If `$name` contains something, it will be sent to that URL as a query parameter.

Comment: What else do you suggest? I néed to use a value from one page in the other.

Comment: @Chrism your method is fine for redirecting a client to another page (for whatever reason, we can't know though). Just specify a full URL

Comment: But I am facing an issue...the get works in the other page, but when the other page hits the submit button, the get goes outside the scope. How about setting a cookie?

Comment: @Chrism I don't understand. Maybe add some more detail about what you are doing to your question. Maybe show some more code